System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.1.2.0
I am trying to create a .Net Standard 2.0 library (I am using visual studio 22)
I encountered the following problem while running the project:
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

This is my .csproj file:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>   
    <CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
  </PropertyGroup>


  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="RestSharp" Version="106.15.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog" Version="4.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Extensions.Logging" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Console" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.File" Version="6.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>

There were a lot of problems with the packages, so I added the line:
<AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>

But it only solved some of the errors (I downgraded some of the packages to solve other errors) but I was left with the above error.
I am new to .net and would really appreciate your help.
(And if you ask why .net standrad then it's because I need to produce a package from my code that will fit several different versions (both core and framework)

It seems peculiar that you are creating an EXE that targets .NET Standard. As far as I'm aware, you usually target .NET Standard in library projects, i.e. that create a DLL, so that can then be consumed by EXEs and other DLLs that target various frameworks. Maybe that's the issue.

@jmcilhinney is right. For running a project you need to have Exe  with     net8.0

@jmcilhinney I removed the EntityFrameworkCore packages from my project, and now it runs.  I run it as a console app now and I do have Exe However, I no longer have database access.

If you have another idea, I would appreciate it. My program works well in .net8 but I need to make a package from it that will work for framework4.6.2 what can I do?

May I know why you delete that sms/email issue post  ？ I am interesting on that issue.

I am testing it and find you delete it 3 mins ago, that issue should be related to your company policy right ? Your commany's firewall forbid it, hope you can share more details, it may help others who will face same issue in the furture.

@JasonPan I deleted it because I'm stupid... it wasn't related to the api calls. The reason it didn't work is because the web service I use wasn't load due to a configuration problem. And it broke everything...

Thanks for your feedback. Have a nice day.
